# Run own code elevated at will from non-elevated plugin DLL

Tags: c++, windows, dll, uac

I am making a suite of 64-bit plugin DLLs for a Windows host application using Visual Studio/C++, and from the current version onward, the setup.exe that they come in creates a single shared user-writable folder under ProgramData in which I cache all sorts of (non-user specific) data files.  Older versions didn't have that folder yet.

However, the distribution of my plugin binaries is often out of my hands too.  They are repackaged by a 3rd party bundle which can only do dumb file copies of the DLLs (so no real setup.exe functionality I need like creating folder + set permissions).  And since my binary DLLs are all 100% self-contained, users also historically have a hand of just copying the DLLs around to other machines as they see fit, but that ofc also lacks the new folder setup phase.

I am looking into a workaround to have my DLLs create the folder at runtime if it is missing.  I know I can't elevate the host process in-place whenever I want, but I thought of the following ways:

1. Have an extra "FixSetup" entry point in my DLL, and when the need arises, start an elevated RunDLL32.exe and let it use this entry point in my DLL.
   However, I see all sorts of people all over the place talking about RunDLL being as good as deprecated and advising against using it, but then again that was already since Windows XP and it's still with us.  I also hear of RunDLL having it's own runtime context which can change with every Windows release (like switching to high-DPI aware when that came available), and that it thus is a 'hostile' environment to run in (read it on Raymond Chan's blog IIRC).  Should I really be afraid of using it, or is my use case so simple it can barely break? (no GUI, just a wrapped CreateDirectory call)
2. Create a small "FixSetup.exe" which just does the folder creation, package it into my DLL's resources, and extract-to-temp + run-elevated it at runtime.
   While this would bloat my DLLs (depending on how small I can get the .exe), I feel like it's also a more fragile + convoluted solution than 1. above (with file extraction and all; prob. best to sign the utility exe too to keep HIPS / antivirus from acting funny etc?).
3. Alter my DLLs so that they're actually .exes in disguise which happen to export the host-expected DLL entry points, so that I can call them directly (elevated).
   I know there are some major caveats here (like conflicts between the C runtime being included in DLL or non-DLL mode, Visual Studio prob. not approving of these shenanigans, etc.), and honestly I already feel I need a shower just after talking about this one.  So while theoretically maybe feasible, it is my last resort.

Does anyone have any advise on my uncertainties above?  Or maybe an even better suggestion?

### EDIT

I've already managed to get option 1. working, and while it works seamlessly there's one drawback I spotted: the UAC prompt (understandably) asks whether the user wants to run RunDLL32.exe, signed by Microsoft.  This might confuse/scare people no end (that is: if they even read these prompts...).  I'd rather have the UAC prompt asking about MyPluginSetup.exe signed by MyCompany, so now I'm more inclined to go with option 2. instead.

Comment: Also option 4) maybe, to just use user's appdata folder if setup was never run. The plugin could pop a one-time prompt to advise running the elevated setup, but stop short of requiring it.

Comment: @dxiv: A valid option.  Point is though that the plugins explicitly want to share the data between users; it's truly global per-app data (not insurmountable if done per user, but a bit of a shame not to do it).  Plus that the users don't always have the setup.exe at hand, as in the case of the 3rd party bundled distribution...

Comment: Agreed, but it may still be worth considering as an option, which would appeal to those who work on their own dedicated single-user machines, and prefer "xcopy deployment" without setups or elevation.

Comment: Update: in the end I decided to just revert to saving everything on a per-user basis, making my question moot.  In my case, for now the pros (user-shared semi-r/o download cache) just don't outweigh the cons (nagging about running installers and admin prompts etc.).  So @dxiv: you managed to convince me in the end after all :)